# jenkins get pipeline environment variable in ssh agent plugin sh command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, pipeline, ssh-agent

I am trying to get environment variable declared in pipeline unfortunately i am not getting the pipeline environment variable in ssh agent shell command.

I am trying to get environment variable declared in pipeline unfortunately i am not getting the pipeline environment variable in ssh agent shell command.

Please find the code below:

```
#!groovy
library 'reference-pipeline'


pipeline{
    agent { 
        label 'Weblogic||Tomcat'
    }

    environment{
        HostName='test.prod.com'
        sshserver="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@${HostName}"

        SERVER_ADDRESS='192.25.58.201'
        CONFIG='PRODUCTION'

    }
    stages 
    {
        stage("Check TLA version") 
        {
         steps{
            script{
                    sshagent(credentials : ['SSH_Credentials']) {
                        sh """
                        set -e
                        $sshserver << "EOF"
                         
                        echo "Configuration:$CONFIG"  // output "Configuration: " should be "Configuration:production"
                        echo " Server:$SERVER_ADDRESS" // output "Server: " should be "Server: 192.25.58.201"
                        echo " Server Host  :  $hostname" // output "server host: testgood"
                        echo "started"
                        '`git describe`'
                        echo "ended"
                        
                         cd /var/lib/ubuntu/test-srv/current

                        server_version="`git describe`"
                        echo "Current server version:  $server_version"
                        if [[ $server_version != *'1.0.0_Release'* ]]; then
                            echo "Error: The underlying server version is not 1.0.0_Release Release. Exiting ..."
                            exit 1
                        fi
    EOF                   
                        """


                      
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    post {
        always {
                cleanWs()
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
echo "Configuration:$CONFIG"
```

try:

```
echo "Configuration: ${env.CONFIG}"
```

Comment: Yep..I tried it .not working..it looks like quotes issue.if I change sh double quotes to single quotes config value I'm getting but git describe throws error.

Comment: Could you add the code you just described to your question, using the single quotes around the sh block? And also the error message of the git command